# TouchesBegan on a Sub-ViewController not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController that responds to some touchEvents (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc...).

I've found that when I show this controller using presentModalViewController: it works just fine, but I'm trying to add it's View as a subview of another ParentViewController like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Add SubController
    controller = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 300, 130);
    [view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller release];
}
```

When I do this, it gets added the parent view but it no longer responds to touch events. Is there a way to fix this?

Also, is there a better way to go about this? I know I probably could have used a View subclass for the child view, but it's supposed to use a Nib and I wasn't sure how to handle that without using a ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct you should use a UIView subclass.

The easiest way to load it from a nib is to include the subview in your nib.

- Just drop a UIView into the view connected to the original view controller.
- Then with the view inside selected go to the identity inspector. It's the one that looks like a little ID card.
- The very first field is called *Custom Class*.
- Type the name of your UIView *subclass* here.

If you need a reference to this just create an IBOutlet in your original view controller and hook it up. That way you can set `hidden = YES` until you need it.

In your UIView subclass you might want to override

`- (void)awakeFromNib`
This will get called when the nib first unpacks.

for setting up any gesture recognizers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To load a nib directly into a view :

```
// Get the views created inside this xib
NSArray *views = [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewNib" owner:nil];

// There's probably only one in there, lets get it
UIView *myView = [views objectAtIndex:0];

// Do stuff . . .
[[self view] addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `becomeFirstResponder` in your subview and see whether it receives `touchesBegan`... It is probably so, but it will also possibly make the superview not receive `touchesBegan` if you require it...

Comment: please edit, didn't mean to down vote. I can't remove it unless you edit though.